# How to delay file import in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am storing some `keys` in `sessionStorage`, these `keys` are a response from the login request. Once login is done, in `componentDidMount()` I'm making an API call to get user information. I have created `api.js` file with base URL and header, this header uses `sessionStorage.getItem("keys")` to make further user-specific API calls.

The issue is when the page loads for the first time the headers are null and I have to refresh again to get the header `keys`.

I have delayed the process using `settimeout` but still, the header is null for the first time.

Comment: You can add a condition in componentDIdMount. if your keys are in session storage then call the next API. else not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would something like this work for you?

```
const apijs = React.lazy(() => import('api.js'));
```

This will load the file only when you access `apijs`

Comment: when I use apijs.post, shows an error apijs.post is not function.

Comment: Can add the content of your api.js ? const apijs gets the default export from there...

Answer (score 0):

You can make something like this.

```
<div >
  <span>Hello {user?.email}</span>
</div>
```

If nothing has been registered by user, in header user will just see Hello.

Answer (score 0):

```
const [keys, setKeys] = useState('')

useEffect(()=>{
  const userLogin = () {
    // login
    const { data } = fetch('api')
    const { keys } = data
    sessionStorage.setItem("keys",keys)
    setKeys(keys)
    // so something
  }
},[])

useEffect(()=>{
  if(!keys) return
  const getUserInfo = () => {
     // call api to get user info
  }
  getUserInfo()
},[keys])
```